# List Arrary Double[] entering values

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

Using the examples below the 2nd part I see how to add values to a single dim array.  But the 2 dim array I dont yet understand.  In the 1st example the 1,2,3 I need to get from a database. The DB part I have figured out but how to put in the values I dont know. 
If I was using an array it would be

```
myarray[row][column] = value;
```

so how do I do this with the List?

mylist.add --- something?

```
    List<double []> // creates a list that stores arrays of doubles.

List<double []> myList = new ArrayList<Double>();
myList.add(new double [] {1,2,3});
myList.add(new double [] {4,5,6});



List<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
myList.add(3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using arrays as generic type parameters as you can easily end up with "unchecked" warnings. Use collections (typically `ArrayList`) instead.

So instead of this:

```
List<double []> // creates a list that stores arrays of doubles.

List<double []> myList = new ArrayList<Double>();
myList.add(new double [] {1,2,3});
myList.add(new double [] {4,5,6});
```

Do something like this:

```
List<List<Double>> myList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
myList.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
myList.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
myList.get(0).add(1);
myList.get(0).add(2);
myList.get(0).add(3);
```

Or to initialize together, you'd probably do something like:

```
List<List<Double>> myList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();

List<Double> nested;

nested = new ArrayList<Double>();
nested.add(1);
nested.add(2);
nested.add(3);
myList.add(nested);

nested = new ArrayList<Double>();
nested.add(4);
nested.add(5);
nested.add(6);
myList.add(nested);
```

(You can add `nested` to `myList` before or after adding the elements to `nested` -- either way works so do whatever is clearer to you.)

To retrieve a specific element:

```
double value = myList.get(x).get(y);
```

To set a specific element:

```
myList.get(x).set(y, value);
```

This assumes that the list are already the right size, and that you just want to change the value of an existing element. (In other words, just like `set` behaves on a simple `List`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
```

T should be same. If T is double[] then it should be `new ArrayList<double[]>`()

then `get(index)` which is double array and `get(index)[j]` which is value. same logic        with

> d[i][j] = get(index)[j]

```
List<double []> myList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
myList.add(new double [] {1,2,3});
myList.add(new double [] {4,5,6});

System.out.println(myList.get(0)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about just doing inline initialization of a multidimensional array, I'm pretty sure you just use subsetted braces, like so:

```
Double array2D[][] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6}, 
    {7, 8, 9}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a collection-based solution for two-dimensional arrays? If so, then you're looking for a list of lists.

```
//Declaration
List<List<double[]>> twoDimList = new ArrayList<List<double>>();

//Adding values
twoDimList.add(new ArrayList<double>(1));
twoDimList.add(new ArrayList<double>(2));
twoDimList.add(new ArrayList<double>(3));

//Retrieving values
double value = twoDimList.get(1).get(1); //returns 1
```